# If the gcd of a set of integers are one, will the gcd of their differences also be one?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If the gcd($\{\phi_k\}_{k\in\{1,2,\cdots, n\}}$) = 1 (where $\phi_k\in\mathbb{N}$) and $\phi_p > \phi_q$, $\forall p>q$. How
do I prove that the gcd($\{\phi_p-\phi_q\}_{p>q})=1$? A counter example is most
 welcome? This problem arises in radio interferometry. The antennas are represented by $\phi_k$ and the baselines by $\phi_{pq}=\phi_p-\phi_q$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider $\{1,3,5\}$

Comment: Hi Thanks, this looks correct. What happens if $\phi_1=0$ must be zero?

Comment: Then the set of differences includes the original set of numbers, so the gcd is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\{3,5,7\}$, then their differences are $2$, $2$ and $4$, which have $\gcd$ $2$.